# Libgcrypt11 vs Libgcrypt20

Tags: libgcrypt

I recently got an N1 mail application invite. When I tried to install it in my ubuntu 15.10, I got the error that "Dependency is not satisfiable: libcrypt11". Subsequently I found that libgcrypt20 is present from version 15.04. What is the difference between libgcrypt11 and 20.Is it safe to install libgcrypt11 again from launchpad and proceed with my N1 installation???

Answer (score 0):

Everybody installing N1 in Ubuntu 15.04 or 15.10 have the same problem. You can see here : https://github.com/nylas/N1/issues/156

One "solution" is to install libgcrypt11 from older ubuntu version.

[64-OS's](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb)

[32-OS's](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_i386.deb)

Personally I wouldn't do that. N1 relies on obsolete software and this is not a reason to mess with security packages.

"It should be fixed soon" https://github.com/nylas/N1/issues/269